# How do I programmatically set the view title?

Tags: views, 8

In D8, I have a need to dynamically set the title of a views page display.

I've tried implementing both `hook_views_pre_render` and `hook_views_post_build` and setting the value of `$view->build_info['title']`, but Drupal seems to be ignoring it when setting the page title.

It seems like the code in Views where the title is set is in `Drupal\views\Plugin\views\display\Page::execute()`

The #title property on the render array in that method IS receiving my overwritten value from one of my hooks, but it's still ignore and is using the manually specified title on the display config.

What is going on!?

Comment: Do you have the [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module enabled? It is still missing Views integration (https://www.drupal.org/node/2563647) so perhaps it overrides your title with the global default?

Comment: I do, but if that were the case, then specific views title I specify in the views config would not work either, but it does.

Comment: Is this view using a custom template file?

Comment: What is going on!? The title is set in the route definition. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224217/change-view-title-programmatically

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If someone else is looking for an answer, this is how I achieved this.
I implemented `hook_views_pre_render()` where I called `ViewExecutable::setTitle()`. This allowed me to set the page title.

```php
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'ABC') {
    $view->setTitle('MY CUSTOM TITLE');
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to appreciate you that this answer worked.

Comment: This will only change the title on the page (i.e. h1) and not the title in the head of the document (i.e <head><title>Please work!</title></head>).

Comment: @serverjohn this somehow changed. Working for me in 9.4.7.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to change page title too you can use this snippet

```
\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject()->setDefault('_title', $title);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This no longer works. :-(

Comment: This works, but you also have to override the `_title_callback` to keep your changes, see below

Comment: `$route->setDefault('_title_callback', NULL);`

Comment: There is no need to edit an existing answer to repeat what another answer already said. If you want the other answer to be on top (which helps only with the default sorting), give to the other answer enough votes.

Answer (score 3):

Setting only the `_title` property to set the page title tag was not enough in my case.

Overriding the `title_callback` property did the trick :-)

```php
$title = 'something';
$route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getCurrentRouteMatch()->getRouteObject();
$route->setDefault('_title_callback', function() use ($title) {
  return $title;
});
```

Comment: Did not work. D9.4.5

Answer (score 1):

Implemented using `hook_views_post_render()`. In this example the contextual filter is just added to the title.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_render().
 */
function THEME_views_post_render(&$view) {
    /** @var \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view */
    if ($view->id() === 'events' && isset($view->args[0])) {
        // Get year from contextual argument of the view.
        $year = $view->args[0];

        // Prefix year to title.
        $title = (string) t('@year Events', ['@year' => $year]);

        // Set view and page titles.
        $view->setTitle($title);
        \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteObject()->setDefault(
            '_title',
            $title
        );
    }
}
```